# iOS - NSURLSession Uploads with No Internet Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, file-upload, nsurlsession

I'm writing an app that allows users to take pictures, and sends POST requests to the server when the user wants to upload a picture. The problem is, I'm not sure how I should handle the upload process when there is no internet connection.

My goal is to have the app somehow "store" the image the user wants to upload, and then when the connection comes back up, regardless of whether the user is in the app or not, to upload that image in the background. When the picture is done uploading, I also want to notify the user of the successful upload.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm thinking I first need to check if there is a connection or not when the user clicks Upload (should be easy), but I'm not sure how I would "listen" for when the connection comes back up and proceed to upload that picture in the background.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to make the Upload function invisible to the user.  If there is an Internet connection, do the upload. If not, you can store the picture for a later time when the app is running and an Internet connection is available. Of course, then you would need two continuous precesses, one to check for the availability of the Internet and another to check if there are any stored pictures to upload. Whenever the upload is done, then you can notify the user within your app.

If it's a requirement that the upload be done in the background when the app isn't running, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you don't need a separate step to upload the picture when the user taps the Upload button and the Internet connection is available -- just always put the picture in the To-Upload file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical situation for apps that uploads stuffs on the internet. What you need to do is:

> 1. Implement Reachability class to check for internet connections.
> 2. User only press upload once and you need to take that content, store in a "queue" array and save that array in your device.
> 3. Everytime app is active, check the content of the array:

```
if (array!=empty) { 
   loop on NSURLSession to upload those content
   onCompletion {
      remove the content from the queue array;
      notify user;
      and save the queue array back to device (even if it's empty); 
   } 
} else {   
   everything is uploaded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First whenever user clicks on upload a picture, store the picture in your application directory or convert the image to base64 string. And keep them in a queue.
2. Implement Reachability class, you will find it [here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

With the help of reachableBlock and unreachableBlock, you will notify when internet is available.

3. Then implement a system according to your requirement to check pending uploads, and when you want to upload those.
4. If you use NSURLConnection, Use UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier to keep your connection alive if the app goes to background.